# Mount block file on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, mount, loopback

How can block files be mounted on osx? I tried

```
hdiutil attach filename
```

however this is terminating with

```
hdiutil: attach failed - not recognized
```

hdiutil only seems to work for iso/dmg images. On ubuntu the block file can easily be mounted with

```
mount -o loop filename mountpoint
```

Background: I used vdfuse (http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=33355&start=0) to mount virtual disk files (e.g. vhd). vdfuse itself works fine and the partitions contained in the virtual disc appear as block files on the mount point.

VHD File -> /my/mountpoint/Partition1, Partition2, ...

On ubuntu the block files can be mounted via

```
mount -o loop /my/mountpoint/Partition1
```

however the -o loop option does not exist on osx.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

hdiutil was the right way to go but a crucial ingredient are the parameters.

The command

```
hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -nomount filename
```

perfectly mounts the block file as a block file system. Afterwards you can mount any fs like Chris S pointed out.

Comment: Just in case anyone gets stuck here... this command will give you something like `/dev/disk1`. You can run `hdiutil mount /dev/disk1` to actually see the files inside. It will print out the location of the mount point, something like `/Volumes/Untitled`

Comment: Doing this gives me 3 devices for partitions with filesystem, but does not expose the 4th empty partition. Is it possible to expose empty partitions, too for creating filesystems on them?

Comment: @Sam in my case i got `/dev/disk3` and I tried to type `hdiutil mount /dev/disk3` and it gives me `hdiutil: mount failed - No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the partition have a filesystem? Usually you mount it with something like `mount -t ntfs /my/mountpoint/Partition1 /mnt`

Comment: thanks, this would be usually the way to go. however this would require /my/mountpoint/Partition1 to be a block device...
It the same reason you cannot mount an iso by 

mount /path/to/iso /path/to/mountpoint

Comment: Why not just make a memory-disk device that's file backed? Off the top of my head I think it's `hdid /my/file` and it will return a block device name.